# Modifying a column type with data, without deleting the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column which I believe has been declared wrongly. It contains data and I do not wish to lose the data.

I wish to change the definition from varchar(max) to varchar(an integer). I was under the impression I cannot just alter the column type?

Is the best method to create a temp column, "column2", transfer the data to this column, from the column with the problematic type, delete the problem column and then rename the temp column to the original problematic column?

If so, how do I copy the values from the problem column to the new column?

EDIT: For anyone with same problem, you *can* just use the ALTER statements.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As long as the data types are somewhat "related" - yes, you can absolutely do this.

You can change an `INT` to a `BIGINT` - the value range of the second type is larger, so you're not in danger of "losing" any data.

You can change a `VARCHAR(50)` to a `VARCHAR(200)` - again, types are compatible, size is getting bigger - no risk of truncating anything.

Basically, you just need

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ALTER COLUMN YourColumn VARCHAR(200) NULL
```

or whatever. As long as you don't have any string longer than those 200 characters, you'll be fine. Not sure what happens if you did have longer strings - either the conversion will fail with an error, or it will go ahead and tell you that some data might have been truncated. So I suggest you first try this on a **copy** of your data :-)

It gets a bit trickier if you need to change a `VARCHAR` to an `INT` or something like that - obviously, if you have column values that don't "fit" into the new type, the conversion will fail. But even using a separate "temporary" new column won't fix this - you need to deal with those "non-compatible" cases somehow (ignore them, leave NULL in there, set them to a default value - something).

Also, switching between `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` can get tricky if you have e.g. non-Western European characters - you might lose certain entries upon conversion, since they can't be represented in the other format, or the "default" conversion from one type to the other doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Works for `CHAR` to `VARCHAR` and even trims the padding.

Comment: I am having trouble changing from VARCHAR to TEXT, any ideas?

Comment: @Murilo: since `TEXT` is already **deprecated** and will be removed very soon, I would **NOT** modify a column *to* datatype `TEXT` - use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead, if you really need more than 8000 characters of data

Comment: How about when demoting a data type?

Answer (score 3):

Calculate the max data length store int that column of that table.

```
Select max(len(fieldname)) from tablename
```

Now you can decrease the size of that column up to result got in previous query.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ALTER COLUMN YourColumn VARCHAR(200) NULL
```

Comment: Is this first step necessary if you look at the SCHEMA of the table in the first place?

Comment: you want to decrease a varchar field, so this should be the first step.

Comment: I apologize. I misread and thought he was expanding, not shrinking.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PostgreSQL [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-alter.html#AEN2864), you can simply `alter table`

```
ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN price TYPE numeric(10,2);
```

**But here's the thing**

> This will succeed only if each existing entry in the column can be converted to the new type by an implicit cast. If a more complex conversion is needed, you can add a USING clause that specifies how to compute the new values from the old.

Answer (score 0):

add a temp column2 with type varchar(NN), run `update tbl set column2 = column`, check if any error happens; if everything is fine, alter your original column, copy data back and remove column2.