# SQL Server :: MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()'); not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, masking, sql-function, data-masking

My goal is to mask columns on SQL Server 2019.

I'm following a very easy [guide](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-mask-sql-server-data-using-dynamic-data-masking/).

I run this query against `AdventureWorks2014` and I create a copy of `Person.Person`:

```
SELECT  [BusinessEntityID]
      ,[PersonType]
      ,[NameStyle]
      ,[Title]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[MiddleName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[Suffix]
      ,[EmailPromotion]
      ,[AdditionalContactInfo]
      ,[Demographics]
      ,[rowguid]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
      INTO [Person].[PersonMasked]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[PersonMasked]
  ORDER BY BusinessEntityID
```

I'm now going to mask the column `FirstName` as is written in the guide:

```
ALTER TABLE [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[PersonMasked]
ALTER COLUMN FirstName NVARCHAR(10) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()');
```

And I receive the error:

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 30, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Completion time: 2021-11-23T15:32:43.0426983+01:00
```

Where am I wrong?

Where can I find the function `FUNCTION = 'default()'` in SSMS?

Comment: It has nothing to do with that function. The `FirstName` column has names that are larger than 10 characters, thus your `ALTER` is interpreted as trying to shrink the column in an irresponsible way. Your guide uses a different table where that column is already that small. (For completeness, the functions are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking#defining-a-dynamic-data-mask) -- note that they are not scalar- or table-valued functions in the SQL sense.)

Comment: Yes! thank you @JeroenMostert, it worked as soon as I used `NVARCHAR(50)`. Should I reply my own question or do you want to reply?

Comment: If it were up to me I'd probably close it as a typo or something, it doesn't look like the sort of thing many other people would run into. If you disagree feel free to write up an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is related to the change of nvarchar precision to 10 rather than to the

```
FUNCTION = 'default()'
```

If you have any data with values longer than 10 characters they are going to be truncated and this will result in loss of data.

Just do:

```
ALTER TABLE [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[PersonMasked]
ALTER COLUMN FirstName NVARCHAR(50) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()');
```

Helpful links:
[Altering column size in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650278/modifying-a-column-type-with-data-without-deleting-the-data?rq=1#:%7E:text=4%20Answers&text=As%20long%20as%20the%20data,you%20can%20absolutely%20do%20this.&text=You%20can%20change%20a%20VARCHAR,no%20risk%20of%20truncating%20anything.)
[What happens when you modify (reduce) a column's length?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27223/what-happens-when-you-modify-reduce-a-columns-length)